# Eloquent user structure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to have 3 different user types on my website. An `admin`, an `artist` and a normal user called a `follower`.

I could create separate models / migrations for each, but thought maybe there is a better way to do this?

If I create a single model and a migration, then each user will have extra fields that belong to a different type of user, right?

How are these things done in general? Any recommendations / ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default `User` model for all of them, since they most likely all have a very similar structure (a username, an email, a password).

I would create another model called `Role`, and join the users and the roles with a joint table `role_user`.

This way, when you want to check if a user is allowed to do something, you look at what role he has and you can then determine if he's allowed to do that certain action.

You can even push it forward and make a `Permission` model, which is linked to a `Role`, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you! That's actually exactly what I did, following the series on Laracasts. So I am headed in the right direction then.. :)